# Get output larger than the variable On a password Generator using random

Tags: python

Alright, So I have a variable with characters from A-Z, Numbers, Symbols And upper/lower case. But when I try to make it print out a password with more characters than are in the variable, It says this:

```
 File "/usr/lib/python3.8/random.py", line 363, in sample
    raise ValueError("Sample larger than population or is negative")
ValueError: Sample larger than population or is negative
```

Is there a way to be able to repeat letters or just bypass this?

Also, Here's the code it's used in.

```
chars= ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z","A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z","$","%","&","(",")","*",",","-",".","/",":",";","<","=",">","?","@","[","]","^","_","`","{","|","}","~","0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"]
def massprint():
  againagain = int(times)
  even=0
  odd=1
  consec=0
  rand=0
  
  while againagain >= 0:
    time.sleep(float(speed))
    againagain -= 1
    if eocr=="e":
      print(even,flush=True, end=" ")
      even=even+2
    elif eocr=="o":
      print(odd,flush=True, end=" ")
      odd=odd+2
    elif eocr=="c":
      print(consec,flush=True, end=" ")
      consec=consec+1
    elif eocr=="r":
      print(random.randint(int(randlowcap),int(randhighcap)),flush=True, end=" ")
    elif eocr=="p":
      password=random.sample(chars,letters)
      divider = ""
      password = divider.join(password) 
      print(password)
    else:
      print("Unrecognized. Type either e, o or c or r")

  if againagain<=1:
    print(" \n")
print("Do you want to print even numbers,odd numbers,\nconsecutive,random numbers or password? ")
eocr=input("e/o/c/r/p ")
time.sleep(1)
times=input("And how many times should it do this? ")
time.sleep(1)
speed=input("Okay, And What speed should it print the numbers, \nAnswer in seconds. (0.02 Is Default) ")
time.sleep(1)
againagain = int(times)
if eocr=="e":
  print("Alright, The final number will be",str(againagain * 2))
  varcontinue=input("Is this okay? (y/n) ")
  if varcontinue=="y":
    print(" ")
    massprint()
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Done!")
  else:
    exit()
elif eocr=="o":
  print("Alright, The final number will be",str(againagain * 2+1))
  varcontinue=input("Is this okay? (y/n) ")
  if varcontinue=="y":
    print(" ")
    massprint()
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Done!")
  else:
    exit()
elif eocr=="c":
  print("Alright, The final number will be",str(againagain))
  varcontinue=input("Is this okay? (y/n) ")
  if varcontinue=="y":
    print(" ")
    massprint()
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Done!")
elif eocr=="r":
  time.sleep(1)
  randhighcap=input("And what do you want the highest random number to be? ")
  time.sleep(1)
  randlowcap=input("And what do you want the lowest random number to be? ")
  time.sleep(1)
  print("Alright, It will print",str(againagain),"random numbers \nWith a high cap of",randhighcap,"\nAnd a low cap of",randlowcap)
  varcontinue=input("Is this okay? (y/n) ")
  if varcontinue=="y":
    print(" ")
    massprint()
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Done!")
  else:
    exit()
elif eocr=="p":
  letters=int(input("Alright, How many characters should the password have? "))
  time.sleep(1)
  print("Okay, It will print",times,"passwords,\nEach with",letters,"characters each")
  varcontinue=input("Is this okay? (y/n) ")
  if varcontinue=="y":
    print(" ")
    massprint()
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Done!")
else:
  exit()
```

Edit: Here are the values of the variables in the code.

```
chars= ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z","A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z","$","%","&","(",")","*",",","-",".","/",":",";","<","=",">","?","@","[","]","^","_","`","{","|","}","~","0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"]
```

and letters=input

Comment: Can you share sample values of `chars` and `letters`?

Comment: Sure. I'll edit the post now

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem.

Comment: Did you check `help(random.sample)` before using it? It clearly says : "Chooses k **unique** random elements from a population sequence or set.". Your question could just be reduced to "How can I select random non-unique- elements from a list in python", and the answer is to use `random.choice`.

Answer (score 1):

You need `choices`, rather than `sample`.
Here is a reduced example.

```
chars = "abcd123"
from random import choices
for letters in range(3, 10):
print(choices(chars, k=letters))
```

Output:

```
['b', '3', '3']
['d', 'a', 'c', '1']
['b', '1', 'a', 'd', 'b']
['2', 'd', '2', 'c', 'd', '3']
['a', 'a', '1', 'b', 'd', '3', '1']
['3', '2', 'b', '3', 'd', '3', 'd', 'c']
['1', 'c', 'c', 'b', 'c', '3', '2', 'c', '3']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can multiply your chars string to ensure that it is at least as long as the value of letters.  This will produce the minimum number of repeated characters while preserving the relative probability of each one.

```
import random

chars    = "0123456789ABCDEFabcdef"
letters  = 38
password = "".join(random.sample(chars*((letters-1)//len(chars)+1),letters))

print(password)
# 46A5BaD9A9c1e4e503672EaFf7dcDbBC2b830F
```